# Spritekit iOS app main thread freeze with no apparent error or deadlock

Tags: multithreading, ios7, sprite-kit, freeze

I have a question from France for you so I hope my english won't be too bad.

This is my very first question to the community and first of all I'd like to thank you all of you for all the useful tips and answers I already read here for few months and helped me a lot for my very first iOS app.

I'm very new to the iOS dev world so I hope my questions won't be too basic.

Here it comes :

I have a Spritekit game running "pretty" well with no identified issue at this time except that in some very rare case the app freeze and never "recover". It's a kind of breakout game so I have balls and bricks and I use the Apple physicworld and physicbodies of Spritekit. Let's say that one run every 500 the main thread freeze. At first I investigated for deadlocks because I use a bit of multithreading (GCD). But nothing seems wrong on this side. In order to simplify the investigation for the community I did the following changes : no GCD at all in my code. Nothing in the update method of the scene. Everything is now running in the main scene. I would be happy to post some code but not sure what could be relevant since I have no GCD and update code anymore.

Only the main thread seems buged.

Below is the btrace of the main thread hoping it can help. The trace is always the same each time it freezes.

```
    * thread #1: tid = 0x519fe, 0x00000001941224d0 libsystem_m.dylib`__sincosf_stret, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00000001941224d0 libsystem_m.dylib`__sincosf_stret
    frame #1: 0x000000018f2b864c PhysicsKit`b2SeparationFunction::Evaluate(int, int, float) const + 112
    frame #2: 0x000000018f2b79d0 PhysicsKit`b2TimeOfImpact(b2TOIOutput*, b2TOIInput const*) + 928
    frame #3: 0x000000018f2bfac0 PhysicsKit`b2World::SolveTOI(b2TimeStep const&) + 1144
    frame #4: 0x000000018f2c0318 PhysicsKit`b2World::Step(float, int, int) + 280
    frame #5: 0x000000018f2af248 PhysicsKit`-[PKPhysicsWorld stepWithTime:velocityIterations:positionIterations:] + 260
    frame #6: 0x000000018a38ce08 SpriteKit`-[SKScene _update:] + 616
    frame #7: 0x000000018a39ffc8 SpriteKit`-[SKView(Private) _update:] + 260
    frame #8: 0x000000018a39dab0 SpriteKit`-[SKView renderCallback:] + 876
    frame #9: 0x000000018a39b794 SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 76
    frame #10: 0x000000018a3baa90 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 288
    frame #11: 0x00000001002ffc80 libglInterpose.dylib`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 172
    frame #12: 0x000000018a114cbc QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 36
    frame #13: 0x000000018a114ac8 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 300
    frame #14: 0x000000018840fe74 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 364
    frame #15: 0x00000001874c08e0 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 192
    frame #16: 0x00000001874cee90 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #17: 0x00000001874cedf0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
    frame #18: 0x00000001874cd014 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1620
    frame #19: 0x000000018740dc20 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
    frame #20: 0x000000018d0f5c0c GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
    frame #21: 0x000000018a53efdc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1156
    frame #22: 0x0000000100117308 MyGameName`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd37bf0) + 116 at main.m:16
    frame #23: 0x000000019400baa0 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Thank you very much for your time and if you need more info or code sample do not hesitate to ask me.

Have a great weekend,

Gradlon

Comment: You will have to post your code for us to analyze, specifically any area where you use GCD and considering the call stack anything that happens in the scene's update method. It's actually quite easy to interfere with Sprite Kit through GCD - to rule that out remove any usage of GCD from your code or at least change all "async" calls to "sync" calls respectively make them all run on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer LearnCocos2D. In order to simplify the investigation for the community I did the following changes : no GCD at all in my code. Nothing in the update method of the scene. Everything is now running in the main scene. I would be happy to post some code but not sure what could be relevant since I have no GCD and update code anymore. Hoping someone would have an idea ^^

Comment: Do you run code in the contact callback methods? If so try commenting that. Are you sure the game is freezing, not crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, SIGABRT or other?

Comment: Thank again for your feedback. Yes, just freezeing and actually I can still very poorly interact with it (for exemple I can still pause the game but I have to wait for 60sec before any touch or action is taken into account and proceeded). I have plenty of code in the contact callback so I am going to review it a little bit before posting additional code, following your advice. Thx

Comment: you aren't creating another instance of SKView anywhere? Because this is the behavior you get when running two instances of skview simultaneously on a device.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guy because it helped me to review critical things. I have no double skview but I think I have finnaly found the things that was making my app so freezed : I double checked all the crazy stuff without any finding and finally I think it was due to a simple "division by 0" when manipulating a ball sprite velocity property. That's life but at least thanks to you I did a great double check of many things.